# Correct way to write this query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that basically is searching by price, though sometimes the items may have a discount on them and this price isn't stored in the DB, only the discount percent and dates the discount runs between are, so we have to work out the price of the item on the fly to see if it should be included.

Additionally, if the item is an auction we ignore the sale price and just look at the `start_price` and `max_bid` to work out the current price (max bid is only set if the item has at least 1 bid).

We know it is NOT an auction if `start_price == buyout_price`, so know we have to figure out if the item is on sale or not and if so calculate the sale price to see if to include it in their requested price range.

I have this code..

```
SELECT
    whatever
FROM
    auctions AS a
LEFT JOIN
    ..............
WHERE
    ..............
AND
    IF(a.start_price == a.buyout_price AND a.discount_start_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND a.discount_end_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND a.discount > 0, (a.buyout_price - ((a.buyout_price / 100) * a.discount)), IF(a.max_bid > a.start_price, a.max_bid, a.start_price)) >= '500' AND IF(a.start_price == a.buyout_price AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() > a.discount_start_date AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < a.discount_end_date AND a.discount > 0, (a.buyout_price - ((a.buyout_price / 100) * a.discount)), IF(a.max_bid > a.start_price, a.max_bid, a.start_price)) <= '700'
AND
    ..............;
```

As you may be able to make out I'm trying to get all results with prices between 500 - 700.

I'm also getting a error which appears to have something to do with the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, though not sure why!?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== a.buyout_price AND  a.discount_start_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND a.discount_e' at line 1
```

Comment: The equality operator is `=` in SQL (not `==`).

Comment: But I'd really prefer that long `IF(...)` to be rewritten with `AND` and `OR`

Comment: @ypercube is expressing more than just a preference, incidentally... using `IF()` in the `WHERE` clause is going to defeat a lot of potential optimizations that might have used indexes to eliminate a large portion of rows.  The same thing applies to `CASE` or any other expression that involves columns as arguments and makes things in the `WHERE` clause [non-sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), forcing the server to evaluate that expression for every row in the underlying tables that can't be eliminated by another means.

Comment: @ypercube ahhhh.... good catch haha....

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hmmm thanks. I will see if I can rewrite it, that is unless anyone provides one in an answer :P

Comment: I honestly don't know how to rewrite it just using `AND` and `OR` whilst returning the correct value to compare against.

Comment: @Brett well, the first problem, of course, is that your query wasn't syntatically valid, so you should correct the `==` issue, and see where that leaves you.  The rewrite would perhaps be more obvious if you think in simplified terms -- the server "might not" take the time to evaluate all conditions within an `AND` if at least one condition is obviously false.  You will need `AND`, `OR`, *and* `()` some parentheses to group expressions with, to craft the equivalent expression.  You're at an optimization disadvantage anyway since some calculations are inevitable, based on the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Write yourself a view that produces, in a single column, the value of `price` that you're interested in.  It might be a `UNION` of a few different criteria.  When you're done you'll have a view of all items with two columns: the id and the price.

Join that view to whatever else you need (perhaps including the original price), and *voila*.

Tip: skip `IF` and just use `AND` and `OR`, per the SQL standard.  And eschew `LEFT JOIN` unless you know -- and know why -- you can't use a proper inner join.  If the database is pervasively unreliable in that regard, it will lead to more pain than all the outer joins in the world can alleviate.